# How to write test for when redisClient errors using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, jestjs

I am stuck on writing a unit test for when the `redisClient` fails for the `createClient` call. Any idea on how I can write this. Below you will find what I have so far.

```
const asyncRedis = require("async-redis");

class redis {
    constructor(redisHost, redisPort) {
        this.redisHost = redisHost;
        this.redisPort = redisPort;
    }

    async init() {
        try {
            this.redisClient = asyncRedis.createClient({
                port: this.redisPort, 
                host: this.redisHost
            });
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(`Error creating client due to: ${error}`)
        }
    }
}

module.exports =  redis;
```

redis-test.js

```
test('init on error', async () => {
        jest.mock('../../src/redis/redis')
        const redis = require('../../src/redis/Redis');

        redis.mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
                init: jest.fn(() => { throw new Error(); }
            )};
        })

        expect(await redis.init()).toThrowError(Error());

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mocking your code, you should be mocking the `async-redis` library code.

You need to mock the `createClient` method to always throw an error. So that you can check your catch flow is executed.

This part, you got it right `jest.fn(() => { throw new Error(); }`, always return an error.

I am no expert in NodeJS, sorry I am not able to provide detailed source code.

Comment: This was the issue. I was trying to mock the code instead of the `async-redis` libary. Was able to get it on my own but your answer pointed me in the right direction. Thanks a bunch.